# Is there an easy way to swap a rigged character for an updated one?

Tags: rigging

I have a character that's in a scene and I didn't like how he was weight painted and some anatomy needed to be tweaked, now it looks better than before. But I edited the model from its own file where it's just the character and not from the scene he is in. I was thinking there must be a way to update the old model to take over with the new version, considering it's not unusual that when there's a collaboration effort there's a need to update an asset.

Is there something for that kind of situation in Blender?

Manually, it ends up being a real challenge, copy, paste, parent, unparent, unbind, bind. I'm still trying to get it done, so far Blender crashing, not getting something done in the right order having to start over. Parts moving when unbinded as it was moved when binded. Now the fingers aren't bending as the modifiers are in the wrong order. Still at it. It's a real headache.

Comment: You linked the character into your scene file and made a proxy of the armature rig, or did you append the character? I usually work on a single character file with the rigging and all the materials, etc., and then link into my scene file and proxy so that I can update the main character file and it updates once reopening the scene file.

Comment: @Craig D Jones I have no idea how to link or proxy anything in Blender. I just copy and paste the characters into the scene as that is the only way I know how.

Comment: See the [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/linked_libraries.html) for more info about linked libraries.

Comment: @dr. Sybren Getting any useful information out of the blender manual is like learning how to drive by reading the car's owner's manual.

Comment: @EricHuelin then help us improve it!

Comment: @dr. Sybren It is written like an appendix not as a learning tool. You have to approach it like someone comes to that manual what would they need to know to be able to use the tool or action described. Each tool or action should have an example, any button mentioned should show when it can be used and where is it located. That essential component is why I have to dismiss the manual and instead scrub the internet and watch YouTube videos just to understand how to use Blender.

Comment: @dr. Sybren Look at the outstanding answer from Craig D Jones, if the Blender manual was similar for every aspect, Blender would be way more widely accepted, embraced, and invested in, it's that simple.

Comment: @EricHuelin feel free to invest time in the manual. I'm already busy developing Blender Cloud and working on Blender itself. We need more people, it's that simple.

Comment: @dr. Sybren The manual is a bicycle and I want it to be a car, I doubt there's anything I can do to convince anyone to trash the whole thing  and start over. Might as well scream "To hell with Ton Roosendaal I'm running the show now!" not gonna happen. I"ll try to find other more possible ways to contribute to Blender.

Comment: I did pitch the idea of linking answers here in the manual some years ago but didn't follow up.

Comment: @EricHuelin I am actually inclined to feel it works better as an index - most documentation for APIs and stuff works like that, and I find that format very usable for learning. All that we need is an additional get started guide to help users get over the confusion of not knowing how all the little bits of information fit into the overall pattern.

Comment: This is getting off-topic, but I second @GiantCowFilms here; it's not useful if you don't already know what a modifier is, but once you do (thanks to an abundance of youtube tutorials etc.), it's perfect for e.g. looking up what the options of the *Screw* modifier do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: main character]Okay, say you have a main character file complete with rig and extra shapes for your bones. Save your rig and character as a group, and then close.
[image]
Open your Scene file, and choose Link from the File menu. Browse to your character file, go to Groups, and choose the group that represents your character.[image]
Once in scene, while selected, choose Object>Make Proxy and then choose your rig name from the menu.[image][image][image] This will allow you to then use your rig in pose mode and key frame the bones, while protecting your character mesh from changes. Make your changes upstream in your character file and reopening your scene file will pull the changes in.[image]

Comment: I keep failing to recreate your steps. All I get in my scene is the bones of the rig nothing else. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you make sure to group the rig and the character mesh and save the file? Did you link the Group or the Object rig instead? If you link in the group and it is all grouped in the character file, you should be able to see it in the 3d view.

Comment: @ Craig D Jones I selected the rig and all the mesh  in the outliner, did Shift + G in the 3D view, chose "children" saved. Only the rig appears and an empty when I use append in the scene.

Comment: I don't know where 'children' came into play, I group the object mesh and the rig. Try on a simple file with a cube and a bone, and see what happens.

Comment: @ Craig D Jones https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxG3K.jpg

Comment: Select all, ctrl-G to group, save, close. New file, Link, browse to file, choose Group, choose the specific group, presto. While selected, go to Object> Make Proxy and then choose the armature from the list of objects.